# node.js server external access not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have set up a node.js server that is supposed to serve HTML files from a directory to clients. It should also log any connecting and disconnecting clients. Both work perfectly, but only locally. I have already forwarded traffic on `port 3000` to my server and deactivated its firewall. What else can I do to enable external access?

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');
//app setup
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000, ready);

function ready(){
    console.log('setup completed\nlistening on port 3000\n\n');
}

app.use(express.static('public'));

//socket setup
var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket){
   //some code
}
```

Comment: How do the clients access the app, via your external IP address?

Comment: that's the plan, however none of those external connections seems to work :(

Answer (score 0):

> i have already forwarded traffic on port 3000 to my server

Thats the wrong way round. Your server listens on port 3000, but webservers offer there service under Port 80, so you have to forward Port 80 to Port 3000.

> and deactivated its firewall.

Bad idea. Just open one port (80 or 3000 depending on where you do port forwarding). And usually Routers on the way will also block certain ingoing connections, so check that too.

Comment: i tried setting the external port to 80 and the internal (an interval) to 3000 - 3000
it still doesn't work :( did you mean something else?

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't do the trick :(
can you think of something else that could cause this issue?
(i've revised the code once again and configured the router to forward traffic from port 80 to port 3000)